# alpha argument doesn't work as expected when plotting with Terra

Tags: r, r-raster, terra

I am trying to replicate a plot that I have made in `raster` using the new(ish) `terra` R package but the `alpha` argument in `terra::plot` does not seem to work the same way as it does in `raster`.

I am trying to use the alpha layer to indicate uncertainty in the base (coloured) layer. Below is some simplified code indicating my problem. Using the `raster` package, the alpha layer changes the transparency based on values of each individual pixel. When using `terra` this doesn't seem to work.

I think I am using the latest version of `terra` (1.3.4), and I am on a Mac (version 15.5.11).

```
library(terra)
library(raster)

par(mfrow=c(1,2))

plot_cols<-terrain.colors(n=5)

## raster package
raster.template<-raster(xmn=1, xmx=5, ymn=1, ymx=5, nrows=5, ncols=5)

legend.ras.comm<-raster.template
legend.ras.comm[]<-rep(c(5,4,3,2,1), 5)

legend.ras.alpha<-raster.template
legend.ras.alpha[]<-rep(c(0.9,0.7,0.45,0.2,0), 5)

plot(t(legend.ras.comm), col=plot_cols, legend=FALSE, axes=FALSE, box=FALSE, main="Raster package")
plot(t(legend.ras.comm), col="#000000", alpha=legend.ras.alpha, add=TRUE, legend=FALSE)


## terra package
raster.template<-rast(xmin=1, xmax=5, ymin=1, ymax=5, nrows=5, ncols=5)

legend.ras.comm<-raster.template
legend.ras.comm[]<-rep(c(5,4,3,2,1), 5)

legend.ras.alpha<-raster.template
legend.ras.alpha[]<-rep(c(0.9,0.7,0.45,0.2,0), 5)

plot(t(legend.ras.comm), col=plot_cols, legend=FALSE, axes=FALSE, main="Terra package")
plot(t(legend.ras.comm), col="#000000", alpha=legend.ras.alpha, add=TRUE, legend=FALSE, axes=FALSE)
```

[image: Plot output]

Any help with this would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can now do this with `terra 1.3-22`

I get, using your code:

```
## raster package
library(raster)
legend.ras.comm <- raster(xmn=1, xmx=5, ymn=1, ymx=5, nrows=5, ncols=5, vals=rep(c(5,4,3,2,1), 5))
legend.ras.alpha <- setValues(raster.template, rep(c(0.9,0.7,0.45,0.2,0), 5))
legend.ras.comm <- t(legend.ras.comm)
## terra package
library(terra)
legend.ter.comm <- rast(legend.ras.comm)
legend.ter.alpha <- rast(legend.ras.alpha)

par(mfrow=c(1,2))
plot_cols <- terrain.colors(n=5)

plot(legend.ras.comm, col=plot_cols, legend=FALSE, axes=FALSE, box=FALSE, main="Raster package")
plot(legend.ras.comm, col="#000000", alpha=legend.ras.alpha, add=TRUE, legend=FALSE)

plot(legend.ter.comm, col=plot_cols, legend=FALSE, axes=FALSE, main="Terra package")
plot(legend.ter.comm, col="#000000", alpha=legend.ter.alpha, add=TRUE, legend=FALSE, axes=FALSE)
```

[image]

With `terra` you can also use a single value that affects all colors

```
plot(legend.ter.comm, col=plot_cols, alpha=.75)
```

Or change the transparency by color. Something like this:

```
plot_cols_alpha <- terrain.colors(n=5, alpha=seq(.75, 1, .05))
plot(legend.ter.comm, col=plot_cols_alpha)
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. That solved my problem, though I did have to use a workaround. In `terra`, plotting the alpha layer as above doesn't work if there are NAs (i.e. areas of ocean if you're plotting on land, etc.). I managed to get it to work in `terra` by reclassifying NA as 1 the alpha mask, making them fully transparent.

For a reproducible example, put the following two lines of code after the layers are created using `raster`:

`legend.ras.comm <- extend(x=legend.ras.comm, y=c(1,1))
legend.ras.alpha <- extend(x=legend.ras.alpha, y=c(1,1))`

Comment: The problem with `NA`s is a bug that has been solved in the development version. You can install it with: `install.packages('terra', repos='https://rspatial.r-universe.dev')`